# The Secure ADB mode is enabled

Tags: adb

After I connected the device with the ADB tool, I entered the ADB command to prompt the following information:
"The Secure ADB mode is enabled. Please use the GM Secure ADB Client tool to authenticate first."
May I ask how to solve this problem

Comment: Please clarify why you think that this is a programming problem - as apposed to a problem caused by you not having the credentials/accessrights to leave the secure mode. Your current descriptions reads like "The door is locked, I do not have the keys. How can I open the door?" On StackOverflow your question should be about specific programming problems.